# Need Linq expression to create list of string from dictionary of object (containing list)

Tags: c#, linq

Need linq expression to get list of distinct Iternary.Name from all dictionary entry's value's Iternary.Name.

Objects are below format:

```
public class IternaryInfo
{
   public string Name  { get; set; }   
   public Iternary[] IternaryList { get; set; }   
}

public class Iternary
{
   public string Name  { get; set; }   
}

Dictionary<String, IternaryInfo> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, IternaryInfo>();
```

Is this poss in one expression or have to go with looping.

tried - `dictionary.Select(x=>x.Value.IternaryList).ToList()`, but not sure, how to pick -Name field from Iternary.

Comment: added tried option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to:

- flatten the lists using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) and then
- project the `Iternary`s to their `Name`s using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) and then
- use [`Distinct`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct) to get only distinct values

  ```
  var result = dictionary.Values
                     .SelectMany(v => v.IternaryList)
                     .Select(i => i.Name)
                     .Distinct().ToList();
  ```